# wp8 Soundeffect can't stop

Tags: windows-phone-7, audio, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, soundeffect

I use soundeffect to play sound from byte array and all things go alright, but i cant stop playing the sound because no method called stop() in Soundeffect, how i can stop it ?

The code:

```
private void playFile(byte[] file)
    {
        try
        {

            if (file == null || file.Length == 0) return;


            SoundEffect se = new SoundEffect(file, microphone.SampleRate, AudioChannels.Mono);
            SoundEffect.MasterVolume = 0.7f;
            if (stop != 1)
            {
                FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
                se.Play();
            }
            else
            {
                //Here should stop, how !
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ee.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: From your code I'm not sure what you are trying to stop in the else since nothing is actually started (since the play is in the if of the same condition)

Comment: no it's work, and all thing go alright .. but i don't know how to stop it .

Comment: my question is what are you stoping there since in the code you published you have "SoundEffect se" as a local variable so next time playFile is called it will just create a new one and you will stop a new SoundEffect instead of the original one

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling `.Dispose()` on your `SoundEffect` object? According to the [**documentation**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.audio.soundeffect.aspx),

> When a SoundEffect object is destroyed, all SoundEffectInstance
>   objects previously created by that SoundEffect **will stop playing** and
>   become invalid.

Additionally, [**Microsoft recommends**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/design/hh202883%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) using `MediaElement` instead, unless you're developing with XNA Game Studio 4.0. So if that applies to you, you may want to consider using `MediaElement` which *does* have [**Play, Pause, and Stop functions**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.controls.mediaelement%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Comment: i use it , the sound is continue without any changing !

Answer (score 0):

try using SoundEffectInstance

[Sound effect instance](http://rbwhitaker.wikidot.com/playing-sound-effects)

Here's a link to the solution

[Sound Effect Instance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.audio.soundeffectinstance.aspx)

More over `SoundEffectInstance` implements `IDisposeable` so it will have a `dispose()` method as well as `stop()` for the sound effect .

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable for `SoundEffectInstance` as shown below

```
SoundEffectInstance soundEffectInstance;
```

then create an instance of your `soundEffect` after loading the file..

```
soundEffectInstance = se.CreateInstance();
```

after that use this `soundEffectInstance` to `Stop`, `Play` or `Pause` where ever you want in particular scope.

```
soundEffectInstance.Play();
```

Note that `SoundEffect` is used for fire and forget type instances, if you want to control any particular instance of a `SoundEffect` you will need to use `SoundEffectInstance`.

I agree with Benoit Catherinet. If you are trying to stop a particular sound on some event then you must place the stoping code in that event method and for that your SoundEffect instance must be global and not local.

We can better help you if you can explain about what you are trying to achieve.